# MacOs: Prevent Apple Music from launching when clicking AirPods Pro

Tags: apple-music, airpods

I love that my AirPods Pro seamlessly switches between devices. It's not perfect, but it gets it right probably 85% of the time, which is good enough. The problem is that *sometimes* it thinks I want to be connected to a Mac, even when I'm not in the same room.

Clicking the AirPods causes Apple Music to launch and start playing on a Mac. I could understand playing if I already had Music open, but this is just ridiculous behavior. I get that sometimes it's going to guess wrong about which device I want to be connected to, but is there any way to not *launch* Apple Music?

Comment: What are you expecting the AirPods to do when you click them?

Comment: Well I'm not expecting them to open an application on a device I'm not actively using and start playing music that I didn't choose. I have them configured to play/pause when I click. If that's not possible, nothing should happen… or Siri could easily just ask me if I want to launch Music. Playing the first song by the first artist in my library is a ridiculous default behavior.

Comment: It’s doing whatever “play” does on the device it’s connected to. The effect of that command isn’t tied to the AirPods.

Comment: Have you considered adjusting the settings so that it only connects to the mac if it was the last device it connected to? You can configure this in Bluetooth settings “Options” with the AirPods connected.